# Get a user ID from a SQL database with Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, ms-access

I am trying to get an Email Address for the user where person has watch certain number of movies. For Example If the user had watched movie 1,2, and 3 when I run a query for movie 3 that user should show up in my table. But When User Has match all the criteria like when I run a query for user watch movie 1,2,3 and 4 that user should not show up.

Here is the Two Tables:

[image]

[image]

```
SELECT Email 
From Users
Inner Join Movies On Users.ID = Movies.ID
Where(Movies = "Movie 1" AND Movies = "Movie 2")
```

But some how the both User 1 and User 2 is showing up, but it needed only User 1 on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the emails of the users who have seen movies `'Movie1'` and `'Movie2'` you can do this:

```
select u.email
from users u inner join movies m
on m.id = u.id
where m.movies in ('Movie1', 'Movie2')
group by u.email
having count(*) = 2
```

If there is a case that a user has seen a movie more than once, change:

```
having count(*) = 2
```

with:

```
having count(distinct m.movies) = 2
```

Comment: This will work, but a solution should take into that a user could see a movie more then one time. We don't have that detail, but for say did a person purchase razor blades and a razor handle, they could have purchased blades several times, but not the handle. So, this issue was never specified I the problem, but in theory, as user could see the same movie more then 1 time, and thus you get 2, yet they not seen the two different movies.

Answer (score 1):

There are some working solutions here.

However, for typical types of this query, the posted solutions here will fail if the user sees say Movie1 two times. And say a web site, the user might have purchased razor blades several times,but we want Razor Blades AND a Razor handle.

So, the original problem does not state or specify if a user could have seen the same movie more then once, but as a Q + A question, no such restriction was placed on the question, and thus by logic, we can legitimate assume that this is possible.

As I result, my "air" sql would be this:

```
SELECT id, [Name], Email
FROM tblNames
WHERE [Name] is in
   (select [Name] from tblMovies where Movies = 'Movie 1')
   AND
 [Name] is in
        (select [Name] from tblMovies where Movies = 'Movie 2')
```

With above, the user could have seen either movie many times, but they will have to seen both for the above to work. So, use of count would in fact fail, since there is nothing here to suggest that users can't go see the same movie many times.